# How to decrease contents of array in constant time?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

while learning C++ data structures,I was thinking if I could decrease the contents of an integer array by an integer but in constant time. How can I do this if I have enough memory?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: You might wanna narrow it down.

Comment: Do you want to decrease the size of array or all integers it contains?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, without an example its really hard.

You have to iterate over the elements to decrease their value. Their is no way to access every value without iterating over them in O(n) time.

With that being said, If you are decreasing every value in the array by the same then you can use a lazy method and store the decease amount in a separate variable then when the user want to see the value of an element simply reduce it by the stored amount.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that `std::vector::resize` is what you are looking for. Let's say you have a vector with 10 elements and you want to decrease this size by 6 to have only 4 elements, then you could do:

```
int a[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
std::vector<int> v(a, a + 10);
// v contains 10 elements here
v.resize(v.size() - 6);
// v contains 4 elements here
```

the complexity is **O(n)** if reallocation happens (when a bigger memory block must be obtained), but in case the vector is just narrowed down, it should be **O(1)**

Comment: "but in case the vector is just narrowed down, it should be O(1)" if the destruction is trivial (or the amount of elements dropped is constant)

Comment: @DyP: Good point. Although in case of `std::vector<int>` it should be that way.

Comment: +1 This looks correct if that's what they wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

You wish to subtract one value, m, from every element of an array.

In order to achieve this, you clearly need to access every element in the array. And that means that O(n) is the lower bound on the complexity of this task. It cannot be done in constant time.